# How can I add an attribute to a new LI after dropping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, clone, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have 2 lists:

```
<h3>Available page layouts</h3>

<ul id="pagepool" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="I1" class="ui-state-default"></li>
    <li id="I2" class="ui-state-default"></li>
    <li id="I3" class="ui-state-default"></li>
    <li id="I4" class="ui-state-default"></li>
    <li id="I5" class="ui-state-default"></li>
</ul>

<h3>Document structure</h3>

<ul id="docstruct" class="connectedSortable"></ul>
```

Items from the "pagepool" list are dragged (cloned) into the "docstruct" list and are then manually sortable. There can be duplicate page styles in the docstruct list (with duplicated id attributes).

What I'd like to do is request a unique md5 hash via a php file / ajax and add that hash to the rel attribute of the dropped item, after the item is dropped. Everything I've tried so far updates the "pagepool" original item.

How can I modify this to target the cloned item only?:

```
$( "#pagepool li" ).draggable({

           connectToSortable: '#docstruct',
           helper: 'clone',
           revert: 'invalid',
           opacity: '.7'

                              });

$( "#docstruct" ).sortable({
           placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
           revert: true,
           receive: function(event, ui) {
           $.get('ajax/uniqid.php', function(data){ui.item.attr('rel', data)})     
                                                }       
                          });
```

Comment: First, no two elements in your HTML can share the same ID.  Right up front that'll break just about everything.  Second, what's the point of the MD5?

Comment: Agree with Adam - I think the sortable / draggable plugins most likely use ids to target elements, and thus why the wrong ones are being selected. Can you use a different attribute than "id" for each li? HTML5 has a provision for data-{something} attributes to hold things like ids.

Comment: +1 for Adam and wows. Also you shouldn't use the 'rel' attribute, it's only valid for 'a' and 'link' tags as far as I know. Use something like ui.item.data("hash", data) instead.

Comment: that easy huh?! Moved the ids to class and it's working fine thanks!

Comment: the reason for the md5 is that I'm setting up a document outline here; each page has an associated record object (holding field data) which will eventually be stored in a db along with the hash. i needed some way to identify newly created pages in future to facilitate sort order updates etc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is the case, but here is what I've found.

In the receive event, you cannot access the actual item that is being created in the sortable list. Helper points to a clone that is used just for the dragging, item is the original item that you clicked on to drag.

But, the beforeStop event fires just before the receive event. In beforeStop, the item is actually the item in the list. So, in beforeStop you can save the item and then use it in receive.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kcg29/